# Want average, can't add number because of strings. Int doesn't work. Clueless

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
input = "5-9-7-1-7-8-3-2-4-8-7-9"  
word = input.split("-")  
average = sum(int(word)) / len(int(word))
print(average)
```

So the split command gives a list of strings and I can't sum strings the way I want it to do (as numbers, to find the average). I've searched on SO for answers and everyone says to make them integers, but none of the answers work.

The error message I get is: "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'"

Someone in another topic suggested `newvar = [int(s) for s in newvar]` for example but I can't seem to make it work.

Thanks in advance!

To the people downvoting: Mind telling me why so I can improve it? I know there are always the annoying newbies on websites that have been around for a while that keep making the same stupid mistakes, but I don't know the social code here yet.

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: You convert a string to an int by using `int(some_string)`.

Comment: "but I can't seem to make it work." Why doesn't it work? Also, include the line you added (conversion to int) in the code you posted.

Comment: "None of the answers work" and "I can't seem to make it work" are useless as problem descriptions. Show us what you tried and what happened.

Comment: I've tried to do that but then it gives me "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'" as an error when I use it like "average = sum(int(word)) / len(int(word))". I've googled it but it still doesn't work and I'm pulling my hairs out.

Comment: `word` is not a string, it's a list of words.

Comment: @BasdeVries You seem to be exaggerating the problem; *pulling my hairs out*. IMO, this could have been solved if you searched for an answer for each specific error, and not try to find a solution that works out of the box. Converting strings to int is a pretty basic operation that probably has a 1000 dupes already on SO and elsewhere to say the least.

Comment: @melpomene I'll check it out, thanks. Also fixed, thanks for feedback.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I'm a very calm and relaxed person but I'm very new to Python and this was getting really frustrating. I'm on a time schedule so that might be why. I've also been very stressed lately. I've googled but some answers are very advanced and don't help me. Thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 2):

First, the `split` will give you a list of strings.

So you **have to turn each element into a number**

The suggestion is corect, but you need to adapt it to your code.

```
input = "5-9-7-1-7-8-3-2-4-8-7-9"  
words = input.split("-")  
average = sum([int(s) for s in words]) / len(words)  
print(average)
```

Comment: I was using it as a seperate line of code instead of putting it in brackets. I was also not sure what "s" did so that might've been one of my mistakes too. I see what I did wrong, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped you. `s` here is a variable used only in the "brackets", it is supposed to represent each element in the list, successively. (this bracket notation is called "list comprehension" in Python, by the way).

Comment: Wow, you're so calm compared to the rest. I'll be sure to check that out, thanks for the extra information! Have a great weekend!

Comment: also, be careful with the division, if you divide two integer numbers, the division will give the integer part of the result. you can convert at least one of the terms of the division by using float() around it, `float(sum(....)) / len(...)` or `sum(....) / float(len(...)) `

Comment: Also (I will stop my advices after that one :P), check @Neo 's answer, who took the time to separate a bit more the code, and more importantly to show you the results of the various steps. Take the habit of looking at the data after each instruction, for instance by inserting `print`statements between lines, or by executing them directly in the console.

Comment: The more advice, the better! I like looking through the code to see what everything does but I have to do assignments for school and the combination of forced work and a time limit doesn't work well for me haha. Once again, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should turn each item into a number by itself. You can use list comprehension.

```
input = "1-3-5-7-2-4-6-8"
strings = input.split("-")                # strings = ["1", "3", "5", "7", "2", "4", "6", "8"]
numbers = [int(item) for item in strings] # numbers = [ 1,   3,   5,   7,   2,   4,   6,   8]
average = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
```

Comment: Thank you, have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
input = "5-9-7-1-7-8-3-2-4-8-7-9"  
average = sum(map(int, input.split("-")))/float(len(input.split("-")))
```

Comment: Thank you, have a great weekend!